# Need help in validating access token

Tags: spring-boot

I’ve access token passed from UI to my API as bearer token. With that bearer token, client id and client secret I’m able to introspect. But how do I validate the access token with SpringBoot? I’m not finding any examples online.

All I want is, validate if the passed access token is valid or not before sending request to my controller.

Please help. I’m stuck with this since a week

Comment: Are you calling the service directly, or using an api gateway?

Comment: I’m calling directly @Mauricio

Comment: Is this a reactive application? or a simple MVC?

Comment: Reactivity application @Mauricio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information you provided, you can simply use org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter to implement your custom validator:

Declare it

```
@Component
public class CredentialFilter implements WebFilter
```

Inside, override the filter method:

```
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, final WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
    
        //gets the header called bearer_token, or however you store it. You can also use any of the request properties.
        return Mono.just(serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("bearer_token"))
           //if no bearer token throw a simple exception.
           .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(new Exception("Unauthorized"))))
           //validate token with your custom method. If not valid, deals same as before.
           .filter(token -> validateToken(token))
           .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(new Exception("Unauthorized"))))
           .onErrorResume(e -> {
              throw managedException(e);
           })
           //continue the request.
           .then(webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange));

}

        //method to escape throw check.
        protected RuntimeException managedException(final Throwable e) {

        if (e instanceof ISSException.GenericException) {
            return (ISSException.GenericException) e;
        }
        return (RuntimeException) e;
    }
```

This, of course, won't be complete with a exception handler. Luckily, we have the org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.ErrorWebExceptionHandler interface:

```
@Component
public class WebfluxExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler
```

And override the handle method to catch our exception:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> handle(final ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, final Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable.getMessage().equals("Unauthorized")) {
       //put an unauthorized code serverWebExchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
    return Mono.error(throwable);
}
```